# Group by, avg difficulties in SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to get an sqlplus table to give me the workers of each company who make more than the average salary of that company.

(Ex. First National Bank's average salary is $50,000. James and Jane work there and make $80,000, Billy makes $40,000. Fredco's average salary is $30,000. Employee Mark makes $35,000, and Timmy has $25,000 salary. James, Jane, and Mark's names are given as a result.)

However, I've gotten every error under the sun from trying to get it to run correctly. Any help or hints would be very appreciated.

Here's the code for the table's creation. (Ignore the foreign key references: linking to other tables that don't have any of the data needed for this query.)

```
create table works
(employee_name  varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
company_name    varchar(30) NOT NULL,
salary          numeric(9, 2) NOT NULL,
foreign key (employee_name) references employee,
foreign key (company_name) references company);
```

And here's what I have. As of right now, error ORA-01427 is the response. (single row subquery returns more than one row.)

```
select employee_name
from works
where salary > (select avg(salary)
                from works
                group by company_name);
```

Thank you for any hints or help in advance.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c89ce/3

Answer (score 0):

use below query:

```
select w.employee_name from works w 
join (select company_name,avg(salary) salary
from works
group by company_name) q on w.company_name=q.company_name and w.salary > q.salary;
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/41534/1)

Comment: And I feel incredibly stupid for not seeing that earlier. Thank you so much for the help. Seems to be working now.

Comment: you are very welcome, plz see [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f49b0/1), if this was helpful you can accept the answer.

Comment: What if you have data for more than 1 company in the table?

Comment: then he need to use group by, just let me to add the query for it

Comment: @Machinist'sGuardianArchangel answer edited, can you check it

Comment: The new version works great, thanks. I was just excited I was getting an output other than an error, didn't bother to check if it was right. My bad. New output matches my manual math perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
select employee_name
from (select employee_name, salary, avg(salary) over (partition by company_name) avg_co_salary
      from works)
where salary > avg_co_salary;
```

It may be faster than doing two passes through the works table, but then again, perhaps not - it all depends on your data, indexes etc. You'd have to test.